# Testing a callback in Jest

Tags: javascript, callback, jestjs

I have a project I inherited and I am writing up a bunch of tests before I refactor it, and I am having trouble testing a callback.

```
static createNew(data) {
        ApiActions.post(
            '/api/projects',
            data,
            (err, response) => {
    // this is the callback I want to test gets triggered
                if (!err) {
                    this.hideCreateNew();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

ApiActions just builds and executes the ajax request, the third param being the callback.

my test so far:

```
import ApiActions from '@helpers/api';
jest.mock('@helpers/api');

...

it('should createNew', () => {
        const callback = jest.fn((cb) => cb());

        Actions.createNew({ data: [] }, callback);

        expect(ApiActions.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            '/api/projects',
            { data: [] },
            expect.any(Function)
        );

        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor your code such that it becomes more testable by factoring the callback in `createNew` into a separate function and use that as the default callback, but allow other callbacks to be passed in as well.

I believe it should be something like this (may be slightly wrong, but it should illustrate the idea):

```
static createCallback(err, response) {
    if (!err) {
        this.hideCreateNew();
    }
}

static createNew(data, callback) {
    // default to createCallback
    callback = callback || createCallback;

    ApiActions.post(
        '/api/projects',
        data,
        callback
    );
}
```

Now you can test both `createNew` and `createCallback` independently whether the behavior is as expected.

Comment: I did consider this, but this style of function appears multiple times and all callbacks do different things so not easy to have a common one.

Comment: It's not mandatory to have a common callback I don't think. You could just make it mandatory to always pass one. If the `ApiActions` request code is large enough to warrant a single function, it makes sense to abstract it anyway and require a callback for the specific handling of the response. It's highly dependent on context and requires some degree of *taste*. I'm not claiming my solution is the correct one, I can't possibly know in your situation.